# How to change font size of label Apple Watch

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacelabel

I'm kind of stunned I even have to ask this question, but how is it possible to change the size of a label's text on the Apple watch? It doesn't allow changing the size in the Xcode UI, I haven't been able to do it programmatically, and the different font styles don't even change the size.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## With UI

To change the font, you can't use the main template (Text Styles - Body). You should change it to "System", and then try to change font size:

[image]

[image]

## With Code

```
lblSomething.setAttributedText(NSAttributedString(string: "Text Here", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20.0, weight: UIFontWeightBold)]))
```

**Notes**

1- Instead of 20.0, you should use your own font size.

2- Instead of `UIFontWeightBold`, you could use one of the following:

[image]

3- Instead of "Text Here", use your own text.

4- Instead of `lblSomething`, use your label name.

Comment: `UIFontWeightBold` etc. has been renamed to `UIFont.Weight.bold` or just `.bold`

Comment: Hi, Im looking for a way to change the weight without changing the size so it works on all Apple Watch sizes. I set the size in the interface builder.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this programmatically with a `NSAttributedString`:

```
let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(32.0, weight: UIFontWeightMedium)
let attrStr = NSAttributedString(string: "Some String", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font])
label.setAttributedText(attrStr)
```